# Python/Tkinter Designing Arduino Serial Connection Interface Using Labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new at Python and trying to make an interface using labels.
Label inludes Connected and Disconnected messages.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def connectToArduino():

    arduino = serial.Serial(arduinoPort, serialTransferRate)
    arduino.timeout = None
    time.sleep(2)
    arduino.write("S\n")
    Label(root, text="Connected")
    return arduino


arduino = connectToArduino()
arduino.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

How could I add connected / disconnected messages at labels, using if else condition?

Comment: How do you check if you are connected or not? This action should be performed on a cyclic basis (e.g. create a tkinter based object that is checking the connection each "X" seconds) and based on that you can then set the Label text

Comment: Oh - and please fix your import statements (I assume pySerial is missing)

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the Label's ID in a variable

```
## save the ID for the label
lab=Label(root, text="Connected")
lab.grid()

## return the label's ID or it will be garbage collected
## when the function exits
return arduino, lab
```

You can then use

```
lab.config(text="Disconnected")
```

in the code that tests and finds that it has been disconnected.

Comment: lab.config(text="discomnected"). Namerror:'lab' is not defined

Comment: Can't help without code.  Note the comment ## return the label's ID (from the function) or it will be garbage collected when the function exits